# RPG Battle concept not working with specific stats?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a Final Fantasy type RPG battle, but no matter what I try, dictionaries or lists, it doesn't work. I'm trying to make it so I can define the monster once, and reuse it over and over in future battles, without permanently taking away from the monsters stats. This is my code

```
#MONSTER STATS
corpsefinder_stats = {
    "corpsefinder_strength" : 7,
    "corpsefinder_speed" : 1,
    "corpsefinder_mana" : 0,
    "corpsefinder_health" : 45,
    }
#LIVE STATS

#GAME START
if game_start==True:
    time.sleep(0.6)
    print("You wake up, the cold snow on your face as you lie down in bewilderment, wondering where you could of come from and why you are here. As you stand up, you notice a small village in the distance, but before you can even begin to think of venturing over, a small bug-like creature approaches, primed for battle")
    time.sleep(8)
    tutorialbattle=input("\nA CORPSE-FINDER gets ready to attack!\nWhat will you do?\n\n##########\n# Attack #\n##########\n\n##########\n# Defend #\n##########\n")
    tutorialbattle=tutorialbattle.lower()
    if tutorialbattle=="attack":
        print (corpsefinder_stats) ["corpsefinder_health"] - strength
        print(int(corpsefinder_health))
```

Comment: Can you please clarify, what *exactly* is not working?

Comment: Right yeah, I try running the code, everything works and when it gets to this section, it comes up with "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 18 should be
`print (corpsefinder_stats["corpsefinder_health"] - strength)`

Line 19 should be 
`print (corpsefinder_stats["corpsefinder_health"])`

If you are interested in having separate attributes between different monsters, I recommend looking at Classes - https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Tried this but it comes up with

NameError: name 'corpsefinder_health' is not defined

Comment: Edited, although I am still not sure what you are trying to achieve. Can you explain what you are trying to get it to do?

Answer (score 0):

In the last row you reference to `corpsefinder_health` but there is no such var! Its a key into the dict `corpsefinder_stats`.

Use this instead:

```
print(corpsefinder_stats['corpsefinder_health'])
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your line :

```
tutorialbattle=input()
```

It should be :(to take string input)

```
tutorialbattle=raw_input()
```

and later one replace the last line :

```
print(int(corpsefinder_health))
```

with

```
print(int(corpsefinder_stats["corpsefinder_health"]))
```

and finally your code doesn't have `game_start` defined somewhere define it before using . Hope this helps :)

Comment: I hope this might have helped , But i didn't understood +1 and concecutive -1 votes at the same time .:)

Comment: `raw_input()` has been renamed to `input()` in python3, so which one the OP should use depends on whether the OP codes in python 2 or 3

Comment: The question doesn't mention the tags as python 3 . So i hope my answer helps :) .